# Determining what set I have from a bag of lego pieces?

Tags: set-identification

I have a bag of lego pieces that make a set of something but I don't have a box or instructions.  Is there anyway to determine what set it is so I can download/buy an instruction sheet for it...or at least know what I am building?

I found a part piece with a number on it and found out what it was...Spiderman's doc ock ambush.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort complete sets from box of unsorted LEGO](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1598/how-to-sort-complete-sets-from-box-of-unsorted-lego)

Comment: post a picture, or a link to the picture if you can't post it. From the amount of pieces, style and color, it won't be too hard to figure out the series, the approximate year, and then the set.

Comment: Basically, _ask us_, we seem to be pretty good at that game :-) But yeah, a picture is kinda mandatory

Answer (score 8):

I see you already found the answer, but in general, you can use [Rebrickable](http://rebrickable.com). After registering, in the *My RB* menu you can upload the parts you have and the site will tell you which sets you can build out of them. It will even show partial matches, listing the bricks you still need to build them.

Comment: This is a pretty good idea, if you have the patience to accurately enter in all the parts, and provided you can adequately describe the parts in the first place, not to mention finding the right colours. I usually find it easier to locate parts by first finding a set of mine which has the part, then searching the inventory of that set, which is the opposite of what you've suggested. So, points for this being a valid algorithm, but I doubt it is practical.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other answers supplied, look for pieces with stickers on them. Often these contain the set number. A license plate on a Lego car is almost always the set number.

Answer (score 3):

You need to find the rare/unique pieces, and that generally just comes from years of building different sets.  You just know which pieces will be exclusive to a set or at least a limited number of sets.  Then search that piece on bricklink and see what sets it appears in (hopefully only 1!).  Get the inventory of that set online (bricklink, peeron, etc) and see if you have more bricks that make up the set.  If yes, then you're on the right track.  Minifigs are generally the easiest pieces which will tell you what you have.