# Identification of Batman / Joker Set

Tags: set-identification

I went through the [DC Comics Super Heroes](http://brickset.com/sets/theme-DC-Comics-Super-Heroes/) and [Batman](http://brickset.com/sets/theme-Batman) categories of Brickset without being able to identify the origin of this bag of pieces.

[image]

[image]

The only information are `135149` and a year, 2011, written on it, but, [apparently](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/7224/6955), this does not give any concrete information. The number `6062861` is written on a white box, and numerous pieces should give hints to identify it (Joker, Batman, 4 wheels, dynamite, flame, a big red "catapult").

It looks that it is not inappropriate to ask here for such an information (cf. [Jourbac comment](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/2682/6955)), and I don't know how to use [Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/).
Is it the first part of a larger set?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This specific piece, a Tile 2 x 4 with Batman Logo Pattern,

[image]

turns out to be one of the first piece that comes out when [looking for Batman at BrickLink](https://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/searchproduct.page?q=batman), and appears only in one set, the ["Batman: Defend the Batcave" set](https://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?S=10672-1#T=S&O=%7B%7D):

[image]

Comment: Hurray for solving your own question :) Well done.

Comment: Can one select their own answer as the correct answer?
(Montgomery Burns fingers)
"Excellent..."

Comment: @gev You can and should - but you have to wait 2 days IIRC

Comment: Yes, accepting my own answer [is possible](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/), and I will [as soon as I can](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/262759) (48 hours after posting it).